# ARB Pleace holders not working

Tags: javascript

I'm making a localization using  [ARB google's API](https://github.com/shervinafshar/arb-test) but actually the place holder is not working i spent 5 hours to solve this issue with no luck

```
arb.register(
"login", 
{
"title": "Login",
"subtitle": "to your account",
"MSG_BODY_TEST": "This is a test.",
"email": "Email {0}",
"@email": {
 "placeholders": {
   "0": {
      "example": "$123.45",
      "description": "cost presented with currency symbol"
   }
   }
},
"MSG_CURR_LOCALE": "...and the selected language is \"{currentLocale}\"."

}
```

);

```
    arb.register(
"login:ar", 
{
"title": "الدخول",
"subtitle": "الى حسابك",
"email": "البريد الاكتروني {0}",
"@email": {
 "placeholders": {
   "0": {
      "example": "$123.45",
      "description": "cost presented with currency symbol"
         }
         }
            },
    "MSG_CURR_LOCALE": "...and the selected language is \"          {currentLocale}\"."
    }

 );
```

could someone tell me what the problem is please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, try to replace `"email": "Email {0}"` with `"email@placeholder": "Email"`

check this : [reference](https://github.com/googlei18n/app-resource-bundle/wiki/ApplicationResourceBundleSpecification#simple-extensible-and-directly-usable)

also remove the place holder bracket you don't need it

Comment: Wow, that really helps !! you save my day ! thank you :)